# symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7; fails to build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6.1

I am really at a loss. Out of a sudden, my project stopped compiling with:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "_WURM_PROPYLAXE_FREQUENCY", referenced from:
>         -[PBZeitenTableViewController wurmProphylaxeErinnernToggle:] in PBZeitenTableViewController.o
>         -[PBHundEinstellenTableViewController done:] in PBHundEinstellenTableViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

However, as far as I can tell everything is there. There is a static extern constant WURM_PROPYLAXE_FREQUENCY define in my AppConstants.h/.m

Here's the complete message:

> Ld /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy-BARF-bqrdhyplvesjkpcuqgjtdfgqlsfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Easy-BARF.app/Easy-BARF normal armv7
>       cd /Users/michi/Downloads/Easy-BARF-iOS-develop
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy-BARF-bqrdhyplvesjkpcuqgjtdfgqlsfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy-BARF-bqrdhyplvesjkpcuqgjtdfgqlsfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/michi/Downloads/Easy-BARF-iOS-develop -filelist /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy-BARF-bqrdhyplvesjkpcuqgjtdfgqlsfo/Build/Intermediates/Easy-BARF.build/Debug-iphoneos/Easy-BARF.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Easy-BARF.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -lsqlite3 -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework TelerikUI -framework LocalAuthentication -framework NotificationCenter -framework Bolts -framework Accelerate -framework UIKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreData -framework Crashlytics -framework Parse -framework Ensembles -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy-BARF-bqrdhyplvesjkpcuqgjtdfgqlsfo/Build/Intermediates/Easy-BARF.build/Debug-iphoneos/Easy-BARF.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Easy-BARF_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Easy-BARF-bqrdhyplvesjkpcuqgjtdfgqlsfo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Easy-BARF.app/Easy-BARF

Comment: Can you post the relevant snippets from AppConstants.h/.m that show the declaration and definition of `WURM_PROPYLAXE_FREQUENCY`?

Answer (score -1):

This probably means that this file (`PBZeitenTableViewController.m`) isn't being compiled into your binary. To fix this, try this out:

1. Click on the project on the left pane.
2. Navigate to "Build Phases" > "Compile Sources".
3. Make sure that `PBZeitenTableViewController.m` is in the list of source files to compile.

Comment: No, PBZeitenTableViewController.m is in the list :(

Comment: There might be a reason that file is not compiling. Perhaps a random typo made its way in there? What other errors appear when building?

Comment: For example, if I type

Comment: For example, if I type 'UILocalNotification *notification' Xcode will complain `use of undeclared identifier UILocalNotification`, which is clearly defined???

Comment: Now, I added `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in it and it compiles??? What I don't understand is that a have multiple other files using UILocalNotification and they don't require this import. Can you explain to me why?

Comment: It's likely that you're importing another file which contains UIKit into those other files. So they're importing it by association.

Comment: I understand this. Seem logical. However, there is another strange things going on: In my AppConstants.h/.m file, if I declare a new constant it compiles. If I declare a constant, which declared and deleted before, and use that constant, it won't build, where this constant is used???